# How do I write a query that outputs the row number as a column?

Tags: sql, db2

How do I write a query that outputs the row number as a column? This is DB2 SQL on an iSeries.

eg if I have

table Beatles:

```
John
Paul
George
Ringo
```

and I want to write a statement, without writing a procedure or view if possible, that gives me

```
1 John
2 Paul
3 George
4 Ringo
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY beatle_name ASC) AS ROWID, * FROM beatles
```

Comment: that's it. Thanks. Might be worth mentioning that the order by beatle_name part is optional

Answer (score 3):

Check out the row_number() function; you should be able to do this in DB2 via:

```
SELECT row_number(), first_name FROM beatles
```

I'm almost certain this is not part of the SQL standard though, so it is not likely to be portable should that ever be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY BEATLE_NAME) ROWNUM,BEATLE_NAME FROM BEATLES;
```