# How to get an incremental "RowId" column in SELECT using ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: sql, sql-server, dataexplorer

I've been trying to update [a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/668421/top-tags-without-excerpts) on the DataExplorer that we use on our Gaming SE Site for keeping track of tags without excerpts to include an incremental row number in the results to make reading the returned values easier.  There are a number of questions on here that discuss how to do this, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438610/how-do-i-write-a-query-that-outputs-the-row-number-as-a-column) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555454/how-to-generate-auto-increment-field-in-select-query) which appear to have worked for those users, but I can't seem to get it work for my situation.

To be clear, I would like something like this:

```
RowId | TagName | Count | Easy List Formatting
----------------------------------------------
1     | Tag1    | 6     | 1. [tag:tag1] (6)
2     | Tag2    | 6     | 1. [tag:tag2] (6)
3     | Tag3    | 5     | 1. [tag:tag3] (5)
4     | Tag4    | 5     | 1. [tag:tag4] (5)
```

What I've come up with so far is this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TagInfo.[Count] ORDER BY TagInfo.TagName ASC) AS RowId, * 
FROM
(
   SELECT
   TagName,
   [Count],
   concat('1. [tag:',concat(TagName,concat('] (', concat([Count],')')))) AS [Easy List Formatting]
   FROM Tags
   LEFT JOIN Posts pe on pe.Id = Tags.ExcerptPostId
   LEFT JOIN TagSynonyms on SourceTagName = Tags.TagName
   WHERE coalesce(len(pe.Body),0) = 0 and ApprovalDate is null
) AS TagInfo
ORDER BY TagInfo.[Count] DESC, TagInfo.TagName
```

This yields something close to what I want, but not quite.  The `RowId` column increments, but once the `Count` column changes, it resets (presumably because of the `PARTITION BY`).  But, if I remove the `PARTITION BY`, the `RowId` column becomes what appear to be random numbers.

Is what I want to do achievable given the way the tables are structured? If so, what should the SQL be?

To access the forked query, you can use [this link](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/fork/668421).  The original query (before my changes) can be found [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/493693/top-tags-without-excerpts) if it helps in anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the `PARTITION BY` is exactly what is needed. The reason that your numbers look random is that the `ORDER BY` of the outer query is different from the `ORDER BY` of your `ROW_NUMBER()`. All you have to do is make those the same, and the output of the sequence project will have the monotonically increasing value you expect.

Specifically:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TagInfo.[Count] DESC, TagInfo.TagName) AS RowId, * 
FROM
(
   ...
) AS TagInfo
ORDER BY TagInfo.[Count] DESC, TagInfo.TagName
```

Now you aren't partitioning, and the two `ORDER BY` clauses match, so you'll get your expected output.

For what it's worth, you technically don't really even care about having an `ORDER BY` in the `ROW_NUMBER()`, you just want the same order as the final result set. In that case, you can trick the query engine like so by providing a meaningless `ORDER BY` clause in the `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RowId
```

Boom, done!

Comment: Perfect.  This is exactly what I was after.  It looks like the sub query was also unnecessary to perform as well so I cut that out.

Answer (score 0):

A little way around i used its, i add a column to the original table that has a increment value by 1 for example

```
ALTER TABLE ur_table ADD id INT IDENTITY(1,1) 
GO
```

after that you do the query with order by column id

```
select * from ur_table (query) order by id
```

Comment: This would be a quick and dirty solution, but I would think in most situations altering the schema in this manner isn't advised.  And in this case, it's not an option since the SE Data explorer doesn't allow you to perform Alter Table queries.